# Assigning resources to consumers according lists of preferences

Tags: mathematical-optimization, minimization

## TLDR

I'm looking to assign resources from different categories to consumers, optimized according to some priorities linking consumers to resources.

## Example

- The consumers are people, of which there are N<sub>p</sub>.
- The resources are tickets (of which there are N<sub>t</sub> in total) to different attractions (of which there are N<sub>a</sub>), such as zoo, botanical gardens, museum, theatre, concert, etc.
- There is a limited number of tickets for any given attraction and these numbers may differ: say, 6 for the zoo, 20 for the gardens, 9 for the museum, etc.

  N<sub>zoo</sub> + N<sub>gardens</sub> + N<sub>museum</sub> + N<sub>theatre</sub> + ... = N<sub>t</sub>
- Each person submits an ordered list of N<sub>c</sub> < N<sub>a</sub> choices of tickets they would like to receive.
- The total number of available tickets exceeds the number of people: N<sub>t</sub> > N<sub>p</sub>
- Each person must be assigned exactly one ticket.
- The aim is to maximize overall satisfaction in terms of people getting as close as possible to their preferred choices.
- Optional, second-order complications:

  - Couples, or even small groups of friends, might have to be assigned the same kind of ticket, either rigidly or by biasing the cost function.
  - Some people are premium members and some attractions are premium attractions: these premium members should get priority on the premium attractions, should they list them among their choices. Again, this might be done rigidly or by biasing the cost function.

## The questions

- Is there a name for this sort of problem that would help me to look for relevant approaches in the literature?
- Can you suggest any algorithms particularly suited to this sort of problem?

Comment: Not a programming question. Move this to a different site, Operations Research.